# JSON Schema to validate whether or not a file path exists

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am writing a JSON schema, and I want to add a field that takes in a file path. Is there a way to validate if the file path exists (Similar to how `$schema` displays an error when it cannot find the schema file)? Here is what I have:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "properties": {
    "file": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^(\\./|\\.\\./|https?://).*\\.json$",
      "description": "The path to another json file."
    }
  }
}
```

It would look like this in a file, and if the file does not exist, it would display a warning/error.

```json
{
  "file": "../path/to/file.json"
}
```

[image: File path not found.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is `$schema` doesn't resolve to anything. It's an identifier of the meta-schema, not a network reachable uri. It's not meant to be resolved to a network location, although some implementations do try and resolve it.

Second thing, validation itself doesn't resolve any references of a property value, there are packages you can use to resolve refs, but that's not in scope of the JSON Schema specification or the validation mechanism. You can use `pattern` to create a regex of a specific path uri pattern, but that's the extent of the validation.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like what your saying, is that my editor is doing the validation and not part of the spec, which would mean that the editor would have to support this (which they wont).

Comment: some editors do follow the path to fetch the resource, but that behavior is not part of the JSON Schema specification